# Trying to make a new object in show up in a different place every time a method is called (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm probably missing something obvious but I'm an extreme beginner and I honestly have no idea what to do for this. Major apologies if this doesn't make sense.

I'm trying to make a program, so that every time I run 'fireRight()', it makes a new 'fireballRight' (Sprite object), and sets its position relative to the x and y values (the location of the other sprite where they are being 'fired' from).

Basically, every time I run 'fireRight()' I want the program to make a NEW fireballRight that uses the same animation but from a different starting point, while all the previous fireballRight's created continue to exist and animate. Right now, I'm running 'fireRight()' by pressing the spacebar. Everytime I hit the spacebar, instead of making a new fireballRight, it simply speeds up the first one that was made, and does not seem to add a new one.

What am I missing?

Here is the part of my code that is relevant to what I'm trying to do:

```
double rightx = x + 180;
double righty = y + 50;


private int fireballs = 50;


Sprite[] fireballRight = new Sprite[50];

public void init(){

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    fireballRight[i] = new Sprite();
}

}

private int i0 = 0;


public void fireRight(){
i0 += 1;
System.out.println(i0);

new AnimationTimer()
    {



public void handle(long currentNanoTime)

        {      

            fireballRight[i0].setImage("puercosloco/fireballright.png");                                          
            rightx++;      
            fireballRight[i0].setPosition(rightx, righty);
            fireballRight[i0].render(gc, 80, 55);           
        }
    }.start();     
}
```

Please let me know if I'm not providing enough info or if this is too vague.

Comment: There's only one variable, `rightx` for the x coordinates of all the sprites. So 1. they all appear at the same place, and 2. each time you start a new animation timer, you increase the number of times it is incremented in each frame.

Comment: so how do you suggest going about giving each new sprite a different variable for their location? cause I see what you're saying, just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Make it a property of your `Sprite` class. Seeing as you have a `setPosition` method, it looks like you may already have such a property.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `i0` for your animation, because this way you can spawn 50 `AnimationTimer`s but they all point to the same sprite.

```
public void fireRight() {
    i0 += 1;
    int localI = i0;
    System.out.println(i0);

    new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {      
            fireballRight[localI].setImage("puercosloco/fireballright.png");                                          
            rightx++;      
            fireballRight[localI].setPosition(rightx, righty);
            fireballRight[localI].render(gc, 80, 55);           
        }
    }.start();     
}
```

I'm not sure if other stuff are correct, though.

Comment: Good catch. I still think it's more natural to make a local `Sprite` variable than a local `int`, though. (Imagine you used a named (non-local) class instead of an anonymous class: you would have a `Sprite` as a property in that class, not an array and an index...)

Comment: @James_D Definitely. I'm also not too sure whether everything would work out well because David has used so many global variables with potentially 50 parallel animations changing their values. The better way is definitely to move most of the stuff into the `Sprite` class, and maybe make a `SpriteManager` to do the overall control over all of the `Sprite` instances.